# Show the users with most posts in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I want to show Users with most post and thats what i'm do..
I try this in my AppServiceProvider.php:

```
view()->composer('questions.side2', function($view){
        $m = User::leftJoin('questions','users.id','=','questions.user_id')
            ->selectRaw('‌​us‌​er‌s​.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->orderBy('total','DESC')
            ->skip(0)
            ->take(5)
            ->get();

        $view->with('m', $users); 
    });
```

In My Side view :

```
@foreach($m as $user)

   {{ $user->name }}

@endforeach
```

but i still have this error: 
Undefined variable: m (View: C:\wamp\www\qq\resources\views\questions\side.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\qq\resources\views\questions\side.blade.php)

Comment: Did you check if this function is really called? If you put `dd($m);` before `$view->with('m', $user);` what do you get?

Comment: view()->composer('questions.side2', function($view){
   $m = User::leftJoin('questions','users.id','=','questions.user_id')
    ->selectRaw('‌​us‌​er‌s​.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->orderBy('total','DESC')
    ->skip(0)
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
  dd($m);
            $view->with('m', $users); 
        });
But the same error message..

Comment: What's happening is that this function is never started. Do you have a `show` method in Controller right? What is in it?

Comment: In UserController??

Comment: Probably in QuestionController. It is somewhere you are calling the view 'questions.side'.

Comment: Show method in questionController..
public function show($id)
 {
               $question= \App\Question::find($id); 
               $bars     = \App\Question::unsolvedbar();
               return view('questions.view',  compact('question','bars'));
 }

Comment: Is this questions.side included by another blade?

Comment: You are using `$view->with('m', $users);` but I don't see any `$users` variable so you should get error for undefined variable `$users` at first. So, it seems the composer function is not being called at all.

Comment: I fix it but this query i thinks have an error:
User::leftJoin('questions','users.id','=','questions.user_id')
  ->selectRaw('‌​us‌​er‌s​.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')
  ->groupBy('users.id')
  ->orderBy('total','DESC')
  ->skip(0)
  ->take(5)
  ->get();

Answer (score 1):

You are sharing the variable in a wrong way because "with" function expects an array of data, moreover, you are sharing a wrong variable name.

The variables must be passed like this:

```
$view->with([
   'm' => $users
]);
```

Or using `compact()` method, and you **must** change `$users` to `$m`

```
$view->with(compact('m')); //Or => $view->with(['m' => $m])
```